# How can i ask a firestore request that depend on the first firebase response next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I want to make a second cloud firestore query with the uid i receive in the first query but the second query won't wait the first response my code

```
  var {data} = useSWR('/api/report', fetcher);
  var userData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= data ? data.length : null; i++) {
  var id = data ? data[i].uid : null;
  userData.push(useSWR(data ? '/api/${id}' : null, fetcher).data)
  console.log(data, id, userData);
  }
```

Comment: You can put above code into n async function and use await for bothe useSWRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it this way:

```
async function doFunc(){
  var {data} = await useSWR('/api/report', fetcher);
  var userData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= data ? data.length : null; i++) {
    var id = data ? data[i].uid : null;
    userData.push(await useSWR(data ? '/api/${id}' : null, fetcher).data)
    console.log(data, id, userData);
  }
}
```

**Edited:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(false);
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    if (!firstTime) {
      var { data } = await React.useSWR("/api/report", fetcher);
      var userData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= data ? data.length : null; i++) {
        var id = data ? data[i].uid : null;
        userData.push(
          await React.useSWR(data ? "/api/${id}" : null, fetcher).data
        );
        console.log(data, id, userData);
      }
      setFirstTime(true);
    }
  }, [firstTime]);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it, i have an error "Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Comment: Where are you exactly using it in your code?

Comment: Here: 
`export default function Home() {

  async function doFunc(){
    var {data} = await useSWR('/api/report', fetcher);
    var userData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= data ? data.length : null; i++) {
      var id = data ? data[i].uid : null;
      userData.push(await useSWR(data ? '/api/${id}' : null, fetcher).data)
      console.log(data, id, userData);
    }
  }

  doFunc();
  return (`